# Which Functional interface in java.util package has a method with NO arguments and void return type?

Tags: interface, functional-programming, arguments, return-value, void

I was looking for a **functional interface** provided by **java.util** package which **do not take argument** and **returns void**. There are number of Functional interfaces in java.util package like Consume and  Supplier, but i am looking for a functional interface without argument and without return type. I know that i can create some interface like 'Operation' which will serve my purpose, but if it is already available in java.util, it would be good to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `java.lang.Runnable`

Comment: Thanks for reply , I suppose, it would be confusing to use without using as  thread.

Comment: It will be confusing only for beginners, but everything is confusing for them :)